# Error: 'AjaxControlToolkit' is undefined but only on IIS

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis-7, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have an ASP.NET application, which used AjaxControlToolkit. It works fine when I run it from VS using development web server and also working when deployed to testing server.
Now I decided to try it using IIS on my computer. I created Virtual Directory and published site there. But if I'm running it from IIS, I get the following error:

[image: Error: 'AjaxControlToolkit' is undefined]

The same files are located in the bin folder and AjaxControlToolkit.dll is there.

I think maybe I need to change some settings in IIS?

Answer (score 1):

One of the big difference between IIS and VS development server is that in IIS your application run with the AppPool Identity(Network Service) and in VS studio it run with your own account(probably administrator).  "Network Service" should be reader on your bin folder.

Normally you shouldn't have problems in IIS but just to be sure check your folder security, set "Everyone" as reader just to check.

Have you also check your application pool targeted framework?

If you are using impersonation, be sure that your impersonated user is in the IIS_IUSRS group.

Comment: Application pool for this site: ASP.NET v4.0, Pipeline mode: Integrated. Actually problem was resolved by adding Login.aspx as default document. No sure why, probably this page should be loaded first.

Comment: Maybe something to do with
    `<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolKit" %>` in your webPage
or
    `<pages>
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit"/>
      </controls>
    </pages>`
in your web.config.